# Why is addEventListener not executing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using the Vue.js framework, and I am trying to write a demo, and I want to know why the `addEventListener` function is not executing in my code.

This is for a browser:

```
 _initEvents(el, attr, callback) {
    this.$el.querySelectorAll(el).forEach(item => {
        if (item.hasAttribute(attr)) {
            callback(item, item.getAttribute(attr))
        }
    })
}
_compile() {
    this._initEvents('*', '@click', (item, key) => {
        console.log(item)
        item.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
            console.log('yes')
        }, false);
    })
}
```

When I `console.log(item)`, the browser console can press `<button @click="test">yes</button>`, so the function does exist, and the button is in the DOM.

Why can't `item.addEventListener` execute and print 'yes'?

Comment: I think it might help if you provided more background on what you're trying to do as at first glance it looks like a very strange usage of Vue. The `@click` attributes would only be present in an in-DOM template prior to Vue initializing. After you kick off Vue with `new Vue(...)` those DOM elements will all be thrown away and the `@click` won't be present in the DOM Vue generates.

Comment: oh, sorry ,i didn't make it clear. emmm,i'm not to use Vue, i want to learn the source of Vue, so, i try to write Vue . The first step is to achieve `new Vue(...)`,this_initEvents(....) is init click event function. Traverse all Dom to find have `@click` attributes, get the dom , and add events to the Dom,such as `item.addEventListener(...)`. The point is not about `@click` attributes , but why i get this dom to add click events use native js , this addEventListener is no work. I can console this dom is `<button></button>`,this find dom is right.

Answer (score 1):

After Vue **render**, ***'@click'*** attribute will no longer exists in the DOM.
Try an other attribute.

```
<button @click="test" new:click >yes</button>  

this._initEvents('*', 'new:click', (item, key) => {
    console.log(item)
    item.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        console.log('yes')
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: *because it's a reserved keyword.* Ehm, **no**. It's because Vue doesn't support dynamic adding or removing of vue-attributes.